# Как объединить два wp_query в одном и при этом, мне нужно, чтобы не было постов больше 9 и была пагинация

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

У меня есть поиск через  WP_Query с 2 разными запросами, мне нужно объеденить эти два query в один и при этом posts_per_page сделать 9 и добавить как-то в него аргумент paged, чтобы сделать пагинацию

**UPDATE**

Мне нужно сделать поиск по продуктам и также поиск по тегам.
Поиск делаю по таким запросам

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        's' => $s,
        'paged'=> $page,
 );
 $args2 = array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $s
        )
    )    
);
```

Также у меня присуствует фильтрация, если пользователь фильтрует что-то, то к 1 запросу добавляеться еще такой tax_query

```
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'term_id',
'terms' => $filter
```

**Update**

Временным решением я решил сделать, что у меня 2 отдельных wp_query, которые записывают в array id продуктов, а потом третий wp_query уже просто query по тем id с пагинацией. Способ рабочий, но не уверен, что данное решение нормальное

Comment: там ведь можно указывать массив значений для параметров запроса. Вроде `post_type=>['post','product']`

Comment: Если быть точнее, то мне нужно сделать поиск по продуктам и по их терминах. Если добавить в аргументы поиск по терминам, то у меня ничего находить не будет, поэтому я делаю через 2 wp_query.

Comment: Код ваших двух запросов в вопросе напишите

Answer (score 0):

При выборке с использованием tax_query в качестве параметра можно указать массив таксономий. Пример:

```php
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => ['product_tag', 'product_cat']
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => [$s, $filter]
        )
    );
```

Соответственно, следует сформировать эти массивы до запроса. Например:

```php
$searchTax  = array('product_tag');
$searchTerm = array($s);

if( 'если пользователь фильтрует' ) {
    $searchTax[] = 'product_cat';
    $searchTerm[] = $filter;
}

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $searchTax,
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $searchTerm
        )
    );
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что если пользователь напишет в поиск к примеру pizza, а какой-то продукт имеет тег pizza, то мне его показало, но при этом так же показывало мне продукты в которых просто имеется название pizza.(Ну и чтобы они не дублировались). Просто у меня также присуствует фильтрация и она у меня рабочая, мне лишь нужно просто сделать отдельный поиск по тегам, который не будет зависеть от основного. Погуглив я понял что это можно сделать только если использовать несколько query.